# In Big O notation, why is 8^n of O(2^n)?

Tags: big-o

I can't find why the complexity of 8^n is 2^n. More specifically, the question given is to find the complexity of 1/3*8^n-10.

Comment: `8^n` is not in `O(2^n)`, quite simply. `2^n` is in `O(8^n)` but not the other way round. If someone told you otherwise, that person is wrong. A function that takes `8^n` time grows much faster than one that takes `2^n` time.

Comment: If you don't care about the base of the exponent, you can write 2^O(n). For example, 8^n is equal to 2^(3n), and 3n is in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to give the rough guideline of how to prove your statment is incorrect

lets assume that your are right and

$8^n = O(2^n) $
then by definition there exist N (natural number) and M (**constant** real number, bigger than 0) such that for all n> N :

$ 8^n < M * 2^n $

from here we can conclude that
$ M > (8^n)/(2^n) = (8/2)^n = 4^n$

in contradiction to the face that M is a constant, so 8^n is not O(2^n)

you can also show it by using the lim sup definition

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).